# Json search and print

Tags: json, jq

I've been trying to use jq parser to help me extract information from json files.

Here is an example snippet

```
{
  "main_attribute": {
    "name": {
      "display_name": "abc"
    },
    "address": {
      "unit": "1",
      "street": "Dundas",
      "suburb": "Syd",
      "state": "NSW"
    },
    "financial_debt": {
      "bank_loan": true
    }
  },
  "secondary_attr": {
    "income": {
      "pretax": 100000
    },
    "automobile": {
      "make": "Citroen",
      "model": 2015,
      "new": true
    },
    "property": {
      "property_owned": 1,
      "owned_since": 2000,
      "first_sale": true
    },
    "education": {
      "degree": "MS",
      "graduated": 1990,
      "financial_debt": {
        "bank_loan": false
      }
    }      
  }
}
```

I need to find the blocks where "financial_debt" is true. This field could be either in the main_attribute (as a global value) or in the secondary attribute.

Expected output:

financial_debt: bank_loan on "automobile" and "property"

Can you please advise how to go about doing this search using jq?

Comment: Your example does not make sense. `financial_debt` is not `true` but an object. But even then, there's no relation to it being "true" and "automobile" and "property". To make things even more confusing, `financial_debt` seems to be a random property on a random object. First it's on `main_attribute`, then it's on `education`.

Comment: @JeffMercado - This json is formed based on input from different sources (DB). Am open to restructuring but I don't see why it cant make sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means the most efficient way, but it is functional. It returns a boolean value specifying whether or not there is a `true` boolean value under the `financial_debt` property.

```
jq '[recurse | .financial_debt? | select(. != null) | recurse | booleans] | any'
```

Answer (score 0):

**tostream** can be used to find paths containing `"financial_debt"` as follows:

```
  tostream
| select(length==2)
| select(.[0] | contains(["financial_debt"]))
```

with this filter in `filter.jq` and data in `data.json`

```
$ jq -M -c -f filter.jq data.json
```

produces

```
[["main_attribute","financial_debt","bank_loan"],true]
[["secondary_attr","education","financial_debt","bank_loan"],false]
```

This intermediate result can be used along with **reduce**, **setpath**, **getpath** and a filter such as

```
  . as $d
| reduce ( tostream
         | select(length==2)
         | select(.[0] | contains(["financial_debt"]))) as [$p,$v] (
    {}
  ; setpath($p[:-1]; $d | getpath($p[:-1]))
  )
```

to produce

```
{
  "main_attribute": {
    "financial_debt": {
      "bank_loan": true
    }
  },
  "secondary_attr": {
    "education": {
      "financial_debt": {
        "bank_loan": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```